# Getting undefined value while calling web service ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting undefined value while calling ajax.

Here is my fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5pxQb/)

can we add data in json format like ?

```
'north': '44.1',
'south'='-9.9' ,
'east'='-22.4','west'='55.2',
'username'='demo'
```

Comment: hi itsur url is giving the following status : the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded..... you can paste & go the url in your browser

Comment: Your response does not contain the information you're looking for: {"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}

Comment: I am using from this http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html

Answer (score 1):

First of the Json format is not the one you specified

For this

```
'north': '44.1',
'south'='-9.9' ,
'east'='-22.4','west'='55.2',
'username'='demo'
```

the json would be :

```
{
   'north' : '44.1',
   'south' : '-9.9',
   'east' : '-22.4',
   'west' : '55.2',
   'username' : 'demo
}
```

Json is a key value pair **JSON (/ˈdʒeɪsɒn/ jah-soun, /ˈdʒeɪsən/ ja-son), or JavaScript Object Notation, is an open standard format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs. It is used primarily to transmit data between a server and web application, as an alternative to XML.** From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Now passing the json data can be acheived using jquery ajax functionality:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { //pass your data here }
}).done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "I am callback " + msg );
});
```